# SOLR Multi threaded atomic OR in-place updates for document

Tags: solr, lucene, in-place

I have a scenario as follows:

There are 2 separate threads where each will try to update the same document in a single index for 2 separate fields, for which we are using atomic OR in-place updates. For e.g.

id is the unique field in the index

thread-1 will update following info: 
id:1001 
field-1:abc1001

thread-2 will update following info: 
id:1001 
field-2:xyz1002

The updates are done on the same core index asynchronously. 
What i would need to know is that will there be at any time inconsistency in the index. Both the 2 threads will update different fields for the same id field.

Comment: The usual approach is to include the `_version_` field from the original update and then retry the update if it doesn't go through. Since in place updates (meaning specific in-place updates, not the general atomic updates) only touches the column for a specific field, that should be OK.

Comment: Thanx MatsLindh, the field which is common in both threads will be id field itself, will there be some race condition while updating the id field in the index

Comment: If you're _updating the id field_, one of the updates won't have an id to make an update to?

Comment: id will come with every updates

Comment: But you're not _updating_ the id-field?